# Can not display products of a category in the frontend

Tags: product, category, frontend

Can not display products of a category in the frontend.

[image: category frontend]

Answer (score 0):

There could be few possible reasons if products are not showing on fronted
. this could be all or any of the following :

1 - Products are not set in-stock.

2 - Products are not associated with right Website ( i.e if you have multiple websites and en,fr and you have associated products with fr and checking en website or vice-versa or not selected at all ).

3 - Products are not enabled.

4 - Are prodcuts assoicated with right categories or not.

5- re-index your site. with php **bin/magento index:reindex** command. and flush cache

6- If above all are checked and have no issue then there must be some issue with your website configuration ( Store -> Confiugraions -> Web ) some invalid value is set in your **core_config_data** table.